# Has no exported member 'toPromise' rxjs- 5.5.2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ionic3, observer-pattern

Using `toPromise` throws an error

**Old method:**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

**Latest way:**

```
import { toPromise } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

The latest way shows the following errors:

> [ts] Module '"d:/.../node_modules/rxjs/operators/index"' has no
>   exported member 'toPromise'.

*Versions:*

```
 "typescript": "2.4.2"
 "rxjs": "5.5.2",
```

Comment: which version of `rxjs`??

Comment: It is `rxjs: 5.5.2` @Aravind

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of rxjs 5.5.0-beta.5, the `toPromise` method is now a permanent method of `Observable`.

There is no need to import this method anymore; in fact, trying to do so will throw an error.

> toPromise: now exists as a permanent method on Observable

**[Change Log](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#550-beta5-2017-10-06)**    |      **[Github Reference](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/toPromise.ts)**

Comment: Is that due to my `rxjs` version?

Comment: Why can't I maintain the same kind of pattern here too?

Comment: @Sampath https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838807/angular-rxjs-why-dont-i-have-to-import-topromise-anymore

Comment: I guess these files are misplaced and I remember seeing a github issue on the same will update you the issue link in sometime

Comment: It is https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/2868

Comment: That's rapid speed... Was just looking around the issue list there is a comment with the issue link..

Comment: Thanks that was the thing @SurajRao

Comment: Hope you'll update the answer then? We don't need this anymore.

Comment: Your saying to me @Sampath?

Comment: Yes, Hope you'll give the actual reason for that here.

Comment: Yup. Updating in some minutes

Comment: Hey, You don't need to use `import` here? Why we need it if it is inbuilt on `observable` `import`?

Comment: yup!!! Sorry about it. Updated the answer