# What should I use instead of toPromise() when using await on an Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs, angularfire2

[This page](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html) says `"toPromise has been deprecated! (RxJS 5.5+)"` but I've been using it lately with AngularFire2 (when I only want one result) like this:

```
const foo = await this.afs.doc(`docPath`).valueChanges().toPromise();
```

Should I not be doing this? If not, what is the `await` alternative?

UPDATE:

After the answer below I've changed this:

```
const foo = await this.afs.doc(`docPath`).valueChanges().toPromise();
```

...to this:

```
const foo = await (new Promise(resolve => this.afs.doc(`docPath`).valueChanges().pipe(first()).subscribe(result => resolve(result))));
```

Could someone please explain to me how this is an improvement?! Seems like a step backward to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular/rxjs: Why don't I have to import toPromise anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838807/angular-rxjs-why-dont-i-have-to-import-topromise-anymore)

Comment: @zero298 don't dupe vote just because `toPromise` appears in both questions...

Comment: @JonasW. Did you read the duplicate? "toPromise: now exists as a permanent method on Observable"  I take that to mean it isn't deprecated.  Would you rather me post an answer that says "It's not deprecated" or link to a question that says as much?

Comment: @zero298 the question is 1 year old?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just should put after pipe!

```
   .pipe(take(1)).toPromise
```

Comment: toPromise  will retun promise ??

Comment: Should I use `pipe(first())` instead?

Comment: How would we use this with await?

Comment: The `toPromise` method on `Observable` is **not** deprecated: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.2/src/internal/Observable.ts#L329-L343

Comment: Sorry I understood wrong, but you still can use toPromise but not to each observable, only after the pipe. In the new version of Rxjs, you put all your operatos inside a pipe and then after the pipe you can put the toPromise()

Comment: @AdrianLemesCaetano hi adrian - is there a documentation link for this (which observable you can and cannot ? Most of the help/tutorials all have toPromise on the Observable. But I ran into this issue and resolved it with using pipe and take operator. But I'm not sure of the reason why this worked. Thanks

Comment: import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { first, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
const a = new Observable((observer) => {
      observer.next(5);
      observer.next(10);});
    
    // We can use .toPromise chained with .pipe() to make it to work like promise 
    a.pipe(take(1)).toPromise().then(value => console.log(value, "Im a promise"));
    //or we can use first or take(1) to make it to work like a promise
    a.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((value) => console.log(value, 'Observable'));

Comment: Please remove this false claim about `toPromise` being deprecated. This is nowhere to be found, except this very answer.

Comment: Guys, `toPromise()` is being deprecated in v7.0: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/rxjs-7-in-depth-32cc7bf3e5c

Answer (score 5):

`firstValueFrom` and `lastValueFrom` is definitly a better alternative for many reasons:

1. The naming is more readable and self explanatory.
2. The additional ability to select either first or last value.
3. The additional ability to declare a default value in case the observable didn't emit any

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69215890/5191209

Answer (score 0):

Just a few other options for those who want to be crazy:

```js
const foo = await this.afs.doc(`docPath`).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
```

or

```js
const foo = (await this.afs.doc('docPath').get().toPromise()).data();
```

or

```js
const foo = (await this.afs.doc('docPath').get().pipe(take(1)).toPromise()).data();
```

or

```js
const foo =  (await this.afs.doc('docPath').snapshotChanges().pipe(take(1))
.toPromise()).payload.data();
```

But the shortest is:

```js
const foo = (await this.afs.doc('docPath').ref.get()).data();
```

And anywhere you can use `take(1)` you can use `first()` if you want to emit an error.

For more Firebase promises, see [here](https://dev.to/jdgamble555/firestore-observables-to-promises-4m4g).

J