# How to use await in Array.prototype.map to wait for RxJS Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, dictionary, rxjs, observable

How can I await a result inside a map function where getFooBar returns an observable?

Ex code:

```
this.fooBarResponse.fooBars.map(async (x) => {
      x.fooBar = await this.fooBarService
        .getFooBar(x.fooBarId.toString())
        .toPromise();

      return x;
    });
```

foobar.service.ts

```
getFooBar(id: string): Observable<FooBar> {
    return this.fooBarsCollection.doc<FooBar>(id).valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't, mixing promises and RxJs is not optimal. You should switchMap from one observable to the next and have a single subscribe.

Comment: What would this look like?

Comment: Reduce your array of fooBars to a single observable that switchMap from one to the next

Comment: I'm new to RxJS, could you show an example?

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array#map` is synchronous. Use a `for...of` loop instead.

```
for(const x of this.fooBarResponse.fooBars){
    x.fooBar = await this.fooBarService
        .getFooBar(x.fooBarId.toString())
        .pipe(take(1))
        .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either for me. However, it works when I loop over it and subscribe to getFooBar but  doesn't solve the problem of retrieving the result for x.fooBar.

Comment: Here's what my getFooBar method looks like, I'm using firestore ```getFooBar(id: string): Observable<FooBar> {
    return this.fooBarsCollection.doc<FooBar>(id).valueChanges();
 }```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're returning there.

Comment: `(method) AngularFirestoreDocument<FooBar>.valueChanges(): Observable<FooBar>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51677415/10733081 seemed to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your array of fooBars to a single observable that switchMap from one to the next

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, delay } = rxjs.operators;

const fooBarResponse = {
  fooBars: [{ fooBarId: 1 }, { fooBarId: 2 }, { fooBarId: 3 }, { fooBarId: 4 }, { fooBarId: 5 }, { fooBarId: 6 } ,{ fooBarId: 7 } , { fooBarId: 8 }]
}

const fooBarService = {
  getFooBar: x => of(`emitted ${x}`).pipe(delay(500))
};

fooBarResponse.fooBars.reduce(
  (obs$, x) => obs$.pipe(
    switchMap(_ => {
      console.log(`Switching from foobar ${x.fooBarId}`);
      return fooBarService.getFooBar(x.fooBarId.toString());
    })
  ),
  of(null) // start with some random observable
).subscribe(finalEmit => {
  console.log(finalEmit);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.6.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type FooBar. fooBars is a FooBar[]

Comment: Then fooBarService.getFooBar is not returning an observable

Comment: Updated my question with getFooBar method

Comment: What does valueChanges return? It is not an observable if it doesn't have the pipe method unlees you are using an old 5.x version of RxJs.

Comment: Sorry, I used foobar as an arbitrary word for all my variables. I can see how that could be confusing with what getFooBar returns.

Comment: valueChanges is returning `Observable<T | undefined> `

Comment: I edited my answer into a runable script, you can see it works